# Export bookmarks from Android 4.1.2 Stock Browser for use in PC Browser

Tags: stock-android, stock-browser, bookmarks

How can I export bookmarks from my Android 4.1.2 Stock Browser, for use in Chrome and Firefox on my PC?

I've checked the stock browser thoroughly, but could not find anything like the `Export` feature found in desktop browsers.

Would appreciate some help, since I have a ton of book marks on my phone, and need them on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the AOSP browser, you can opt to sync your bookmarks with your Google account by enabling Bookmarks in the sync menu for Google (in Settings app).